# iText7- How to add a canvas object to table?

Tags: java, itext7

Now I used pdfCanvas to graph a rectangle, code like below:
 PdfPage page = pdf.getFirstPage();

```
    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page, true);
    float x = 35;
    float y = 480;
    canvas.rectangle(x, y, 30, 30).stroke();
```

In fact, I want to add the rectangle into a table

```
 Table table = new Table(2);
    table.setWidth(261.5f);
```

iText 5, the canvas can be set to an image object and add to table. But in iText 7 the function doesn't work. How can i draw a picture to a table in iText7?

Comment: may be [this](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext5-building-blocks/rectangle-examples) will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `PdfCanvas` from a standalone `XObject`, transform that `XObject` into an `Image` and then add the `Image` to the `Table`:

```
    Rectangle boundingBox = new Rectangle(20,470,50,50);
    PdfFormXObject xObject = new PdfFormXObject(boundingBox);
    xObject.makeIndirect(pdfDoc);//Make sure the XObject gets added to the document
    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(xObject, pdfDoc);//Create a canvas from the XObject
    canvas.setStrokeColor(Color.BLUE).setLineWidth(3f).rectangle(35, 480, 30, 30).stroke();
    Image rect = new Image(xObject);
    table.addCell(rect);
```

Comment: If it works to your satisfaction, can you upvote and accept my answer so other people with the same problem can find it more easily?

Answer (score 0):

There is a comprehensive tutorial on the developers corner of the iText website, explaining (through various examples) how to add an image to a table.
Check out http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/clone-adding-images-table

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is there a way to set a pdfCanvas to an image?